# How to convert sqlite db into core data in ios

Tags: ios, core-data, sqlite

i have the sqlite db and want to convert into core data model. i also have a look at SqliteToCoredata given in githhub but unable to use properly. so is there any easy way to do that conversion.
additionally i also have csv file. is there any way to convert csv file to core data model.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Of course there's a way. There just isn't any **automatic** way. You'll need to

1. Load your existing data
2. Iterate over each entry
3. For each entry, create a corresponding managed object.

If you're using CSV, you can load the file into an `NSString` (if it isn't too big) and then iterate over each line. If you're using SQLite, you'll need to use either the SQLite API or one of the ObjC-style wrappers like [FMDB](https://github.com/ccgus/fmdb) or [PLDatabase](https://opensource.plausible.coop/wiki/display/PLDB/PLDatabase;jsessionid=2A99A1A8A6E84198A14CCE3465F45445).

Comment: works like  a charm... converted 9 mb sized db to core data